# How to deal with this array correctly?

Tags: variables, compilation-errors

I am using a led strip **WS2812b**, an **ESP8266 (NodeMCU 1.0)** and a gesture sensor **APDS9960**.
I want that when I move my hand from *left to right* and from *right to left* I change the colors of the strip of leds, previously saved in an array of strings:

```
const char * colors [11] = {"CRGB :: White", 
"CRGB :: WhiteSmoke", 
"CRGB :: CadetBlue", 
"CRGB :: SteelBlue", 
"CRGB :: Teal", 
"CRGB :: SlateGray" , 
"CRGB :: MediumPurple", 
"CRGB :: Purple", 
"CRGB :: PapayaWhip", 
"CRGB :: LightPink", 
"CRGB :: Crimson"};
```

But when I'm going to turn on the colors using the functions of the **[FastLed](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED)** library in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i <NUM_LEDS; i = i + 1) {
       leds [i] = colors [2];
       FastLED.show ();
       delay (10);}
```

All I get is this error:

> invalid conversion from 'const char *' to 'uint32_t {aka unsigned
>   int}' [-fpermissive]

I guess the problem is **me** when declaring the *array*, could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want an array of strings containing the (badly formatted) names of variables. Instead you want an array of 32-bit integers containing the values held within those variables.

```
const uint32_t colors[] = {
    CRGB::White, 
    CRGB::WhiteSmoke, 
    CRGB::CadetBlue, 
    CRGB::SteelBlue, 
    CRGB::Teal, 
    CRGB::SlateGray, 
    CRGB::MediumPurple, 
    CRGB::Purple, 
    CRGB::PapayaWhip, 
    CRGB::LightPink, 
    CRGB::Crimson
};
```

Since colours are just numbers, in the (hexadecimal) form of `0xRRGGBB` you just store them as 32-bit unsigned integers.  The names you have there are just such (constant) variables used for easy reference (`CRGB::White` is `0xFFFFFF`).

Comment: Thanks!!! Your recomendation did the work correctly!!!
Thanks again!!!